# bx slider is not working

Tags: jquery, bxslider

Hi bx slider is not displaying images to user for some times.
here we are hiding the div first then after loading the js we are making it to visible
the bx slider div is assigned as visible but not displaying to the user. please help me.......

this my html code:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://www.jockeyindia.com/javascripts/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://www.jockeyindia.com/css/jquery.bxslider_banner.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="divBannerContainer" class="banner_container" style="visibility: visible;">
        <div id="banner">
            <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_slideshow">
            <div class="bx-wrapper" style="max-width: 100%;"><div class="bx-viewport" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: relative; height: 370px;"><ul class="bxslider" style="width: 715%; position: relative; transition-duration: 0s; transform: translate3d(-5000px, 0px, 0px);"><li style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 1000px;" class="bx-clone">
                                    
                                        <a href="women/collection/active?utm_source=homepage&amp;utm_medium=banner&amp;utm_campaign=active-bra-new" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_repBanner_ctl04_ancBanner" target="_self">
                                            <img src="http://static01.jockeyindia.com/HomePageContentImages/219/LargeImages/active_bra.jpg" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_repBanner_ctl04_BannerImage" alt="Active Bra new" onerror="this.src='http://static01.jockeyindia.com/images/noimage_318_139.jpg'">
                                            
                                        </a>
                                        </li>
                
                            
                                <li style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 1000px;">
                                    
                                        <a href="sports-and-leisure/products" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_repBanner_ctl00_ancBanner" target="_self">
                                            <img src="http://static01.jockeyindia.com/HomePageContentImages/222/LargeImages/t_shirt_banner_copy.jpg" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_repBanner_ctl00_BannerImage" alt="Jockey History T-shirt Promo" onerror="this.src='http://static01.jockeyindia.com/images/noimage_318_139.jpg'">
                                            
                                        </a>
                                        </li>
                                   
                                
                                <li style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 1000px;">
                                    
                                        <a href="women/collection/international-collection?utm_source=homepage&amp;utm_medium=banner&amp;utm_campaign=ic-black" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_repBanner_ctl01_ancBanner" target="_self">
                                            <img src="http://static02.jockeyindia.com/HomePageContentImages/220/LargeImages/ic_woman_black_bra_jockey_shop.jpg" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_repBanner_ctl01_BannerImage" alt="International Collection - Black" onerror="this.src='http://static01.jockeyindia.com/images/noimage_318_139.jpg'">
                                            
                                        </a>
                                        </li>
                                   
                                
                                <li style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 1000px;">
                                    
                                        <a href="sports-and-leisure/products?collection=24x7%20men:relax:24x7%20woman" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_repBanner_ctl02_ancBanner" target="_self">
                                            <img src="http://static03.jockeyindia.com/HomePageContentImages/221/LargeImages/sleepware.jpg" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_repBanner_ctl02_BannerImage" alt="Sleepwear Men and Women" onerror="this.src='http://static01.jockeyindia.com/images/noimage_318_139.jpg'">
                                            
                                        </a>
                                        </li>
                                   
                                
                                <li style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 1000px;">
                                    
                                        <a href="men/collection/sport-performance?utm_source=homepage&amp;utm_medium=banner&amp;utm_campaign=Sport-Performance" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_repBanner_ctl03_ancBanner" target="_self">
                                            <img src="http://static01.jockeyindia.com/HomePageContentImages/215/LargeImages/sport_performancepush_jockey_shop_online.jpg" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_repBanner_ctl03_BannerImage" alt="Sport Performance - Push" onerror="this.src='http://static01.jockeyindia.com/images/noimage_318_139.jpg'">
                                            
                                        </a>
                                        </li>
                                   
                                
                                <li style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 1000px;">
                                    
                                        <a href="women/collection/active?utm_source=homepage&amp;utm_medium=banner&amp;utm_campaign=active-bra-new" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_repBanner_ctl04_ancBanner" target="_self">
                                            <img src="http://static01.jockeyindia.com/HomePageContentImages/219/LargeImages/active_bra.jpg" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_repBanner_ctl04_BannerImage" alt="Active Bra new" onerror="this.src='http://static01.jockeyindia.com/images/noimage_318_139.jpg'">
                                            
                                        </a>
                                        </li>
                                   
                                
                            <li style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 1000px;" class="bx-clone">
                                    
                                        <a href="sports-and-leisure/products" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_repBanner_ctl00_ancBanner" target="_self">
                                            <img src="http://static01.jockeyindia.com/HomePageContentImages/222/LargeImages/t_shirt_banner_copy.jpg" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_repBanner_ctl00_BannerImage" alt="Jockey History T-shirt Promo" onerror="this.src='http://static01.jockeyindia.com/images/noimage_318_139.jpg'">
                                            
                                        </a>
                                        </li></ul></div><div class="bx-controls bx-has-pager bx-has-controls-direction bx-has-controls-auto"><div class="bx-pager bx-default-pager"><div class="bx-pager-item"><a href="" data-slide-index="0" class="bx-pager-link">1</a></div><div class="bx-pager-item"><a href="" data-slide-index="1" class="bx-pager-link">2</a></div><div class="bx-pager-item"><a href="" data-slide-index="2" class="bx-pager-link">3</a></div><div class="bx-pager-item"><a href="" data-slide-index="3" class="bx-pager-link">4</a></div><div class="bx-pager-item"><a href="" data-slide-index="4" class="bx-pager-link active">5</a></div></div><div class="bx-controls-direction"><a class="bx-prev" href="">Prev</a><a class="bx-next" href="">Next</a></div><div class="bx-controls-auto"><div class="bx-controls-auto-item"><a class="bx-start active" href="">Start</a></div><div class="bx-controls-auto-item"><a class="bx-stop" href="">Stop</a></div></div></div></div>
                    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {

         //         $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
         //             auto: true,
         //             autoControls: true,
         //             touchEnabled: falsebxsliderbestseller
         //         });
         //$('.bxslider>li').addClass('active-slide');
         var slider = $('.bxslider');
         slider.bxSlider({
             auto: true,
             autoHover: true,
             autoControls: true,
             onSlideAfter: function () {
              slider.startAuto();
             },
             onSliderLoad: function () {
                 $('#divBannerContainer').css("visibility", "visible");

             }
         });

       

     }); 
        
    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You code doesn't look bad, something else is causing this. Try to check the css if the element is displayed none.

Comment: Can you please post your code with HTML.

Comment: please find html code

Answer (score 0):

Seems okay to me just that you need to include jquery library file.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I have added above line to your code.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://www.jockeyindia.com/javascripts/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://www.jockeyindia.com/css/jquery.bxslider_banner.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="divBannerContainer" class="banner_container" style="visibility: visible;">
        <div id="banner">
            <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_slideshow">
            <div class="bx-wrapper" style="max-width: 100%;"><div class="bx-viewport" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: relative; height: 370px;"><ul class="bxslider" style="width: 715%; position: relative; transition-duration: 0s; transform: translate3d(-5000px, 0px, 0px);"><li style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 1000px;" class="bx-clone">
                                    
                                        <a href="women/collection/active?utm_source=homepage&amp;utm_medium=banner&amp;utm_campaign=active-bra-new" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_repBanner_ctl04_ancBanner" target="_self">
                                            <img src="http://static01.jockeyindia.com/HomePageContentImages/219/LargeImages/active_bra.jpg" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_repBanner_ctl04_BannerImage" alt="Active Bra new" onerror="this.src='http://static01.jockeyindia.com/images/noimage_318_139.jpg'">
                                            
                                        </a>
                                        </li>
                
                            
                                <li style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 1000px;">
                                    
                                        <a href="sports-and-leisure/products" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_repBanner_ctl00_ancBanner" target="_self">
                                            <img src="http://static01.jockeyindia.com/HomePageContentImages/222/LargeImages/t_shirt_banner_copy.jpg" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_repBanner_ctl00_BannerImage" alt="Jockey History T-shirt Promo" onerror="this.src='http://static01.jockeyindia.com/images/noimage_318_139.jpg'">
                                            
                                        </a>
                                        </li>
                                   
                                
                                <li style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 1000px;">
                                    
                                        <a href="women/collection/international-collection?utm_source=homepage&amp;utm_medium=banner&amp;utm_campaign=ic-black" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_repBanner_ctl01_ancBanner" target="_self">
                                            <img src="http://static02.jockeyindia.com/HomePageContentImages/220/LargeImages/ic_woman_black_bra_jockey_shop.jpg" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_repBanner_ctl01_BannerImage" alt="International Collection - Black" onerror="this.src='http://static01.jockeyindia.com/images/noimage_318_139.jpg'">
                                            
                                        </a>
                                        </li>
                                   
                                
                                <li style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 1000px;">
                                    
                                        <a href="sports-and-leisure/products?collection=24x7%20men:relax:24x7%20woman" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_repBanner_ctl02_ancBanner" target="_self">
                                            <img src="http://static03.jockeyindia.com/HomePageContentImages/221/LargeImages/sleepware.jpg" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_repBanner_ctl02_BannerImage" alt="Sleepwear Men and Women" onerror="this.src='http://static01.jockeyindia.com/images/noimage_318_139.jpg'">
                                            
                                        </a>
                                        </li>
                                   
                                
                                <li style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 1000px;">
                                    
                                        <a href="men/collection/sport-performance?utm_source=homepage&amp;utm_medium=banner&amp;utm_campaign=Sport-Performance" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_repBanner_ctl03_ancBanner" target="_self">
                                            <img src="http://static01.jockeyindia.com/HomePageContentImages/215/LargeImages/sport_performancepush_jockey_shop_online.jpg" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_repBanner_ctl03_BannerImage" alt="Sport Performance - Push" onerror="this.src='http://static01.jockeyindia.com/images/noimage_318_139.jpg'">
                                            
                                        </a>
                                        </li>
                                   
                                
                                <li style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 1000px;">
                                    
                                        <a href="women/collection/active?utm_source=homepage&amp;utm_medium=banner&amp;utm_campaign=active-bra-new" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_repBanner_ctl04_ancBanner" target="_self">
                                            <img src="http://static01.jockeyindia.com/HomePageContentImages/219/LargeImages/active_bra.jpg" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_repBanner_ctl04_BannerImage" alt="Active Bra new" onerror="this.src='http://static01.jockeyindia.com/images/noimage_318_139.jpg'">
                                            
                                        </a>
                                        </li>
                                   
                                
                            <li style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 1000px;" class="bx-clone">
                                    
                                        <a href="sports-and-leisure/products" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_repBanner_ctl00_ancBanner" target="_self">
                                            <img src="http://static01.jockeyindia.com/HomePageContentImages/222/LargeImages/t_shirt_banner_copy.jpg" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_repBanner_ctl00_BannerImage" alt="Jockey History T-shirt Promo" onerror="this.src='http://static01.jockeyindia.com/images/noimage_318_139.jpg'">
                                            
                                        </a>
                                        </li></ul></div><div class="bx-controls bx-has-pager bx-has-controls-direction bx-has-controls-auto"><div class="bx-pager bx-default-pager"><div class="bx-pager-item"><a href="" data-slide-index="0" class="bx-pager-link">1</a></div><div class="bx-pager-item"><a href="" data-slide-index="1" class="bx-pager-link">2</a></div><div class="bx-pager-item"><a href="" data-slide-index="2" class="bx-pager-link">3</a></div><div class="bx-pager-item"><a href="" data-slide-index="3" class="bx-pager-link">4</a></div><div class="bx-pager-item"><a href="" data-slide-index="4" class="bx-pager-link active">5</a></div></div><div class="bx-controls-direction"><a class="bx-prev" href="">Prev</a><a class="bx-next" href="">Next</a></div><div class="bx-controls-auto"><div class="bx-controls-auto-item"><a class="bx-start active" href="">Start</a></div><div class="bx-controls-auto-item"><a class="bx-stop" href="">Stop</a></div></div></div></div>
                    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {

         //         $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
         //             auto: true,
         //             autoControls: true,
         //             touchEnabled: falsebxsliderbestseller
         //         });
         //$('.bxslider>li').addClass('active-slide');
         var slider = $('.bxslider');
         slider.bxSlider({
             auto: true,
             autoHover: true,
             autoControls: true,
             onSlideAfter: function () {
              slider.startAuto();
             },
             onSliderLoad: function () {
                 $('#divBannerContainer').css("visibility", "visible");

             }
         });

       

     }); 
        
    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: while this code snippet may answer the question, try explaining a bit more.  read a bit about how to improve your answer http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300923/3664960